# StyleX group hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, stylexjs

I was testing the new StyleX library and I was faced with a challenge within it. Is it possible to realize a group hover effect for a component only by using the library?

To make an example. Let's suppose we have this component in Tailwind (the same could be achieved using CSS):

```js
<div className='group'>
  <button className='blue-50 group-hover:blue-40'>Call</button>
  <hr className='gray-50 group-hover:gray-40'/>
  <button className='blue-50 group-hover:blue-40'><i className='dropdown'/></button>
</div>
```

The functioning of this component is straightforward: when we hover over any subcomponent, we apply a lighter color shade to all the siblings.
I tried to do the same within StyleX but I couldn't replicate it **WITHOUT using a state and relying on JS callbacks**.

By reading the StyleX guide I know that [Encapsulation](https://stylexjs.com/docs/learn/thinking-in-stylex/#encapsulation) is not available. However, I was wondering if they have a different approach to reach the same result within the library and without relying on `onMouseEnter`, `onMouseOut`, and other callbacks.

Comment: I'm not sure how stylex affects this but can't you use CSS like `.blue-50 { color: #558 }; .group:hover .blue-50 { color: #669}` ?

Comment: Yes, I know @James, thank you. But the thing is that I want to stick as far as possible to the library so I was wondering if there's a way to do it within it.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is planned but not yet implemented.

Comment: Can you link to the github issue/discussion, please?